# PHP OAuthProvider Returns HTTP 500

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-provider

I'm working on adding OAuth to a RESTful API. Surprisingly, using PHP's [OAuth](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.oauth.php) and [OAuthProvider](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.oauthprovider.php) classes (from pecl/oauth) I've not had any problems with signatures, etc.

Where I am encountering problems is in what happens when errors such as a bad timestamp occur.  I'm setting up my provider as follows:

```
public function authenticate(){
    try {
        $provider = new OAuthProvider();
        $provider->consumerHandler(array($this,'handleConsumer'));
        $provider->timestampNonceHandler(array($this,'handleTimestampNonce'));
        $provider->tokenHandler(array($this,'handleToken'));
        $provider->isRequestTokenEndpoint(FALSE);
        $provider->checkOAuthRequest();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

When all of the handler functions return `OAUTH_OK`, the request is able to proceed as expected. To see what happens when the timestamp is bad, I've written my timestampNonceHandler like this:

```
public function handleTimestampNonce($provider){
    return OAUTH_BAD_TIMESTAMP;
}
```

When I run this, passing a correctly signed request (yes, I'm sure), the response is an HTTP 500.

```
[headers_recv] => HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Wed, 14 Sep 2011 08:47:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.4
Content-Length: 648
Connection: close
Content-Type: 0
[body_recv] => Invalid nonce/timestamp combination
```

The message is right, but surely this [should](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#http_codes) be an HTTP 401.

Am I doing something wrong here, or does `OAuthProvider` just treat any failure as an Internal Server Error?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The draft of OAuth describes the use of 400 and 401 headers in a simple way.

http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#http_codes

The actual OAuth protocol at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849 speaketh thus:

> If the request fails verification, the server SHOULD respond with the
> appropriate HTTP response status code.  The server MAY include
> further details about why the request was rejected in the response
> body.
>
> The server SHOULD return a 400 (Bad Request) status code when
> receiving a request with unsupported parameters, an unsupported
> signature method, missing parameters, or duplicated protocol
> parameters.  The server SHOULD return a 401 (Unauthorized) status
> code when receiving a request with invalid client credentials, an
> invalid or expired token, an invalid signature, or **an invalid or used**
> **nonce**.

And the word "SHOULD", as defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119

> 3. SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
>    may exist **valid reasons** in particular circumstances to ignore a
>    particular item, but the **full implications** must be understood and
>    carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

While I **dont** have a definitive answer, I guess that the authors are **gratuitously** using the 500 code without considering the "full implications" , unless the library hits an actual error each time there is an "outdated" request. But it seems perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks aitchnyu. You're absolutely right. I saw the SHOULD in the docs, too, but had expected/hoped that the OAuthProvider implementation would be pretty close to the letter. I'll hang on to see if anyone has any ideas about where the 500 responses come from before marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: "has any ideas" I am curious myself :-) I am just out of college and given the task of wrangling together an OAuth provider myself.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you add a $provider->reportProblem() inside of the catch?

The [problem reporting extension](http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/12238543/ProblemReporting) is exposed via [OAuthProvider::reportProblem()](http://php.net/manual/en/oauthprovider.reportproblem.php)

If you don't see the expected behavior can you provide the pkg version? I'll file a bug and have it fixed ASAP.

Comment: Hi John. Apologies for the delay in responding. I'll give that a go and get back to you as soon as I can.